# SQL queries - filtering in a one to many relationship

Tags: sql

I am writing a large SQL query and have narrowed down the problem to the following (simple example).

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | -1 |
| 3 | 1 |

Now I want to filter out all ids which never have a status of 1. In this example, I only want to return id 1 since id 3 both can have status 1 and -1. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but this should do the trick.

```
select *
from yourTable T
where not exists(
  select 1 
  from yourTable X 
  where X.id = T.id 
  and X.status = 1
)
```

(sorry, edited: you don't want the records having -1 but 1)

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
select id from my_table
group by id
having sum(status) = -count(id)
```

Comment: Clever solution; though this only returns the id; not full row(s) so you could just use `having count(case when status = 1 then 1 end) > 0`, which would be cleaner as it doesn't rely on specific values other than the `status=1` given in the requirements.  i.e. The solution in this answer works because the only status other than `1` is `-1` & that's the only status with a negative value.  If a new status were added that should also be included/excluded, results may be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub query to filter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable YT 
WHERE id NOT IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT X.id FROM YourTable X WHERE X.status = 1
                )
```

Comment: Nice solution; though [johey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580573/361842) is potentially more efficient (more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/361842)